# Store output results of Hive query via beeline in a string. tried running with Popen as well but did not work

Tags: python, hive, subprocess, hiveql, beeline

I am running a hive query from Python script. I was able to run it with out any issue when i used subprocess.getstatusoutput, but unable to store the result into a variable. So i tried to do with Popen, i get an error saying unable to

```
dd1 = '10-Sep-12'
table = 'testing_table'
1> query = "select distinct(input__file__name) from <db_name>." + table + " where as_of_date =" +"'"+ dd1 +"'"+ " limit 2"

2> cmd = 'beeline -u "jdbc:hive2:<connection string>" -e "'+query + ';"'

3> stat, query_output = subprocess.getstatusoutput(cmd)
```

This is working but when I try to print query_output, it prints all the output (like 'info' tags about all the stages and the exact o/p of query)

instead of getstatusoutput, when i use subprocess.Popen or subprocess.check_output I am getting an error as below:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'beeline -u "<connection string>" -e "select distinct(input__file__name) from <db_name>.<table_name> where as_of_date =\'10-Sep-12\' limit 2;"'
```

Comment: __"when I try to print query_output, it is again executing query"__  This is really curious. How did you conclude that?

Comment: Yeah , i did some more analysis and found its not running for second time, its just printing. I have edited the question.@OluwafemiSule

Comment: finally i am able to solve it by adding few commands to beeline. beeline --silent=true --showHeader=false --outputformat=dsv

Comment: Good job! Glad you got it working

Answer (score 0):

## **Attached is a python snippet to read from a file with table list and run hive query for each of the tables in the list and append the results into a file using subprocess**

> The cmd variable stores the command to be executed which is called
>   from the subprocess fns and the output is stored into the variable
>   which is later written to the file. The next set of steps reads the
>   file created in the first step and does another query and writes into
>   into another file.

```
import subprocess
cmd= """ hive -e "use database; show tables;" """
val= subprocess.check_output(cmd,shell=True)        
fl = open('/home/ouput_all_table_list.txt', 'w')
fl.write(val)
fl.close()

fl = open('/home/ouput_all_table_list.txt', 'r')
content = fl.read().splitlines()
for var in content:
    tbl_nm= "'" + var + "'" 
    cmd_ay= 'hive -e "use database; select collect_list(cast(file_dt as string)) as dt, collect_list(cast(cnt as string)) as cnt, '+ tbl_nm +' from (select count(1) cnt,file_dt from database.' + var + ' group by file_dt having count(1) > 0  order by file_dt desc) a;"'
    print cmd_ay
    cmd_out= subprocess.check_output(cmd_ay,shell=True)
    print cmd_out
    fh = open('/home/ouput_all_hive_count_data.txt', 'a')
    fh.write(cmd_out)
    fh.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, I have used below commands and I got the output

```
import subprocess

beeline_connect = "beeline -u $<url_variable> -e" # I have connections url string saved in Linux global variable
query = "select count(*) from Schema.tableName where name = 'Matt';"
command= f"{beeline_connect} '{query}'"

output = str(subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True))
op1=[x.strip() for x in output.split("|") if x.strip().isdigit()]
countme=op1[0]
print(f"count is: {countme})
```